# How to Keep the socket live

Tags: visual-c++, network-programming, tcp

We are working on communicating between Filezilla Client and Filezilla Server having two proxies in between them. Between the two proxies we are having 2 tcp connection.

filezilla client -> P1 --2----- P2 -> filezilla server.

The problem we are getting is while upload filezilla client will send the entire data to P1 and P1 send the data to P2. But P2 recv. speed is not as fast as P1 sending speed. P1 will close the connection after some time but as the P2 is still trying to recv data from P1 so it will not be able to recv and it will fail.

Is there any way to keep the soket alive till the other end will recv the data completely?

1. I have tried using Linger with different timeout options. but it's not handling all the scenarios.
2. I have tried setting the socket option keepalive, but still the same problem persists.

Can anyone please help or suggest me something?

Comment: This should not happen.  FTP is based on a couple TCP connections.  TCP has a flow-control mechanism built in - the endpoints will adjust their window size to prevent any part of the link becoming overloaded.  As long as the proxies are exchanging some data, the sockets should not be dropped.  Why does the client subsystem of P1 close the socket?  What error/status message/log does it generate?

Comment: P1 is having two sockets, for e.g in case of upload one socket with filezilla client(sock1) and one socket to send data to P2(sock2). once it's finished sending data to P2 than it's closing both the sockets sock1 and sock2, as a result communication channel between P1 and P2 is broken resulting in file transmission failed..

Answer (score 1):

When P2 receives information that the connection is closed from other end it should read remaining bytes from the socket before closing the connection from its end.

Comment: P2 will read the remaining data only till socket timeout. for eg.. if we had given the linger with 5sec timeout, the P2 will read data till 5sec and after that it's closing the connection,.. it will not read the entire data P1 has sent..

Comment: @Nidhi, disable automatic connection shutdown performed by system (linger). Do shutdown in your code, when there are no more data to be read.

Comment: How i can make sure at the P2 level that we have consumed all the data sent by P1, if i am keeping the socket open at the P1 level and i am trying to get the entire data at the P2 level, i am getting the data at the P2 level but the socket remains open at the P1 level resulting in failed retrieving  directory listing itself in filezilla(i.e i am not being able to connect to filezilla server itself).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Try to make it more clear, maybe using different words. This is how I understand the system: P1 sends all data and closes socket. P2 will detect this closing from P1, but should not close its end of connection until all data is received first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your contribution on this thread, problem has been resolved using SHUTDOWN function....

Regards
Nidhi